# How to exit Apache rewrite engine immediately on condition, without rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file is in the root, and services multiples websites.

It contains a RewriteEngine block.

I'd like to prevent Apache evaluating rules if the host is not (www) www.example.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#If this is not about example.com, it is probably about our other websites, exit here
RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|)example.com$ - [L]
```

however, this leads to a 500 internal error. Probably due to the usage of {HTTP-HOST} is a RewriteRule directive.

So I'm now thinking about something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|)example.com
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
```

But this would require an Apache rewrite and is bad for the performance.

Anyone a suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to prevent Apache evaluating rules if the host is **not** (www)
>   www.example.com

You are using mod_rewrite anyway. The way to do it is skipping the rule if it is **not** *www*, so you have to make sure it is.

Something like this should work in the .htaccess file at root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)            /$1            [NC,L]
```

It's the opposite of what you have tried.

#### OPTION

Following *Arkanon* suggestion, this option assumes there are more domains and applies the rule only to the selected one (example.com), with or without `www.`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)             /$1              [NC,L]
```

Comment: I agree, though you probably want to make the `www` optional in the regex, because I think Erwin is trying to detect the domain (rather than the www subdomain) so that only one site is affected by any rewrites.

Comment: @Arkanon Indeed. That's also a valid interpretation, maybe the right one. Thanks for pointing it out..